# Can i set a variable in php with a double $$ refering to another variable, there by making the variable dynamic

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I want to make a dynamic variable which can change with certain conditions so $foo can either represent the variable $open or $closed.

I'm building a website for automatically organising user input to create a time table or schedule, have tried variable in variable and it works but i discovered something else that also works, for now i dont have a logical presentation for this but i need to know if it is stardard to use $$var because it works.

```
$foo = array('open', 'closed'); 
$open = 1;
$closed = 5;

shuffle($foo); 

echo $$foo;

Is  this ok to use? as $foo will return 1 or 5 which is kind of what i want.
```

Comment: This is possible, but not "standard", since it is considered bad design. It makes reading, understanding and fixing the code a very hard task. Instead use explicit flags.

Comment: @arkascha can you show me a coded example of a more standard way to achieve this, please?